# How do I fix 500 Internal server on error apache server container

Tags: python, apache, docker, ubuntu

I have a docker apache container in a ubuntu 18.04.1, this is supposed to run a python script. Every time I try to go to localhost:8080/script.py it gives this error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
```

To make the image for the container I used this dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Hadoop Engineering
RUN apt-get update
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN mkdir -p /var/lock/apache2
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV LANG C
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2","-D","FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

I already configured the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf with the following directory directive.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    DirectoryIndex index.py
</Directory>
```

I also ran this commands to enable cgi

```
a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod mpm_prefork cgi
```

The python script is really simple

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8')
print('Hello')
```

Apache log

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Jun 13 17:57:35.156583 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 139891709893696] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 13 17:57:35.156694 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 139891709893696] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Jun 13 18:02:36.277642 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 139891709893696] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Jun 13 18:02:44.289177 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 13 18:02:44.289305 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Jun 13 18:02:53.781433 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 8] [client 172.17.0.1:33026] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
[Sat Jun 13 18:03:01.686712 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 10] [client 172.17.0.1:33030] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
[Sat Jun 13 18:03:52.670527 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 7] [client 172.17.0.1:33034] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
[Sat Jun 13 18:03:56.058867 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 9] [client 172.17.0.1:33038] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
[Sat Jun 13 18:03:57.608438 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 6] [client 172.17.0.1:33042] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
[Sat Jun 13 18:03:58.565509 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 8] [client 172.17.0.1:33046] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
[Sat Jun 13 18:04:07.376159 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Jun 13 18:04:15.473822 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 13 18:04:15.473934 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Jun 13 18:04:18.494927 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 9] [client 172.17.0.1:33050] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
[Sat Jun 13 18:13:19.862778 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 8] [client 172.17.0.1:33092] malformed header from script 'index.py': Bad header: Hello
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: normally Apache creates log file and you should check what is in log. There should be details about error. Without details we can't help.

Comment: Don't remember if this is needed, but `chmod +x /var/www/html/your_script.py` perhaps?

Comment: I added the log to the question @furas

Comment: Didn't work @Torxed, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue appears to be that you're not exiting the header block properly. As per the HTTP protocol, headers are separated from the body by a empty `\r\n`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n')
print('\r\n')
print('Hello')
```

This should not only make the line ending on the header correct *(as they too, need to be ended by `\r\n` per header-item)*. But also end the header block by adding in the empty/single `\r\n`.

Comment: I had seen that print line before, but didn't think it was necessary. Thanks, it worked.